# Exploring speed of ants

Tags: entomology, literature, ant

I'm working on developing a model of ant foraging. To do this, I have simulated food morsels distributed randomly within an area, with the minimum distance between morsels being variable. I'm trying to get a good idea of the scale at which I should define the distances. This has to depend on ant walking speed and their usual foraging distance.

I'm not very species-specific in my approach. One study [(1)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Seiki-Yamane/publication/274837150_A_preliminary_study_on_foraging_distance_and_nesting_sites_of_ants_in_Indo-Chinese_lowland_vegetation_Insecta_Hymenoptera_Formicidae/links/552b2a5b0cf2e089a3aa29e6/A-preliminary-study-on-foraging-distance-and-nesting-sites-of-ants-in-Indo-Chinese-lowland-vegetation-Insecta-Hymenoptera-Formicidae.pdf) shows a survey of foraging distance for different species. They found that most of the species had a maximal foraging distance of less than 1m. Some species did go upwards of 10m. I presume this distance would increase with the presence of trails, but to only focus on finding food by exploring, I can keep the distance between food morsels to be 2m-3m.

Now, I also want to figure out the time that it would take an ant to start from the nest and reach the food given its distance. This is where I'm stuck. I wasn't able to find any survey or study on walking speeds of different ant species. I need an approximate 'exploring speed' of ants, which is just time taken to reach a morsel after leaving the nest. Are there any references I could use to estimate this value for my model?

References:

1. Eguchi, K., Bui, T. V., & Yamane, S. (2004). A preliminary study on foraging distance and nesting sites of ants in Indo-Chinese lowland vegetation. Sociobiology, 43(3), 445-457.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's reasonable to try to do this in a species-independent manner, since there is so much difference between ant species. Leaf-cutter ants, for example, will [build trails to forage 200 meters away from their nests](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00265-016-2237-5). Likewise, [ants vary by two orders of magnitude in size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant#Distribution_and_diversity) and the walking speed of an ant will vary accordingly as well. Finally, I don't think that you can reasonably exclude trail-building from your simulation, since that's a key ingredient of foraging.

Bottom line: pick a species to model and look for information on its specific mobility.